# webpage form not sending input to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, web

I have a web page which needs to send data back to a MySQL database but the first two form boxes data is not sent across to the database.

I have very limited php mysql knowledge and cannot figure out the problem on my own.

```
//create the connection 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(!$conn)
{

//Error handler
die("MySQL Connection Error: ".mysqli_error());
}

//Extracting information from the user to add to the outputs table in the Database
if (isset($_POST['confirmbut'])) {
    $sensorname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['sensorname']);
    $sensorip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['sensorip']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['state']);

//Selecting Database and inserting user inputted data to the database
    mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM outputs");
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO outputs(Sensor_ID, Sensor_IP, State, Pending_Update) VALUES ('$sensorname', '$sensorip','$state','1')");

    header("location: insertname.php");
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Switch </title>
    </head>
<body>

<h2 class="title">Please fill in your switches Details</h2>

    <!-- Posts data inserted here -->
    <form method="post" action="insertname.php">

        <!-- Form to enter Device Name, Output IP, State --> 
        <tr>    
            <td>  Relay Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="output name" class="textInput" required="required"></td>
        </tr> 

        <tr>
            <td>  Relay IP:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="outputIP" class="textInput" required="required"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>  Relay State: On = 1  Off = 0</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="state" class="textInput" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="confirmbut" value="Enter" class="enterbutton" > </td>
        </tr>

       </form>  
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Notice how there is a line that says `mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT[...]`? That line inserts data into the database. It is trying to insert data previously defined as `$sensorname` and `$sensorip`. This is defined as coming from the form from inputs named `sensorname` and `sensorip`. You don't have inputs in your form named `sensorname` and `sensorip`. And you don't have anywhere in the code that takes the values from the fields you are using named `output name` and `outputIP`.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk.

Comment: Form elements can't have spaces in the name. Change _output name_ to *output_name*

Comment: I think your `<form action` is the wrong url, since your `header('LOCATION:` is the same after the post... but really... learn AJAX... and don't do `$conn->query('SELECT`s for no reason. Yeah, that's the syntax you will probably appreciate if you like less typing. Then you can do stuff like `$conn->escape_string($stringHere)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you've changed the names of the table rows in your database, but assuming they are the same as in the code, I have corrected your code so that the fields you are trying to insert are pulled from the correct inputs in your form.

```
if(!$conn)
{

//Error handler
die("MySQL Connection Error: ".mysqli_error());
}

//Extracting information from the user to add to the outputs table in the Database
if (isset($_POST['confirmbut'])) {
    $outputname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['outputname']);
    $outputip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['outputip']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['state']);

//Selecting Database and inserting user inputted data to the database
    mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM outputs");
    mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO outputs(Sensor_ID, Sensor_IP, State, Pending_Update) VALUES ('$outputname', '$outputip','$state','1')");

    header("location: insertname.php");
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Switch </title>
    </head>
<body>

<h2 class="title">Please fill in your switches Details</h2>

    <!-- Posts data inserted here -->
    <form method="post" action="insertname.php">

        <!-- Form to enter Device Name, Output IP, State --> 
        <tr>    
            <td>  Relay Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="outputname" class="textInput" required="required"></td>
        </tr> 

        <tr>
            <td>  Relay IP:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="outputip" class="textInput" required="required"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>  Relay State: On = 1  Off = 0</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="state" class="textInput" required="required"></td>
        </tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="confirmbut" value="Enter" class="enterbutton" > </td>
        </tr>

       </form>  
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: would you be able to point out what changes you made please want to learn from my errors thanks.

Comment: First, I changed the form input name to `outputname`, as someone mentioned in a comment earlier, you cannot use spaces. Then changed the references I mentioned in my original comment. `$sensorname` and `sensorname` to `$outputname` and `outputname` for example. You should make sure you heed the warning in the other comment that using escaped strings leaves you open to injection attacks.